# WSL - updatedb (mlocate) is not indexing Windows directories

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, locate

I cannot search for Windows files using locate. Updatedb is not indexing directories from /mnt/c

Answer (score 3):

1. Open /etc/updatedb.conf in your favourite code
2. Remove "9p" from "PRUNEFS"
3. Remove "/mnt" from "PRUNEPATHS"

Comment: None of those are in my PRUNEFS/PRUNEPATHS. But in my case it's indexing /mnt/c but not /mnt/wsl ...